# check multiple conditions on join query - pgsql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, join, sql-view

The below given query will give result if the part `AND course.publish="true"` is removed.But i wanted to check both the conditions on this join query that `deleted_at` column of `course` table has `null` value and `publish` column of `course` table has value`true`.How can i fix this?

```
DB::select('SELECT users.id as user_id,users.name,course.id as course_id,
              course."courseDisplayName",course.created_at,
              subjects.id as subject_id,subjects.subject
               FROM users 
               INNER JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id AND course.deleted_at is null AND course.publish="true"
               INNER JOIN subjects ON course."subjectId"= subjects.id');
```

Error when `WHERE course.deleted_at is null AND course.publish` added:

`"message": "SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"INNER\"\nLINE 16:                INNER JOIN subjects ON  course.\"subjectId\"= subjects.id....\n                        ^ (SQL: SELECT users.id as user_id,\r\n              users.name,\r\n              course.id as course_id,\r\n              course.\"courseDisplayName\",\r\n            course.deleted_at,\r\n         subjects.id as subject_id,\r\n              subjects.subject\r\n               FROM users \r\n               INNER JOIN course ON course.\"userId\"=users.id WHERE course.deleted_at is null AND course.publish\r\n             INNER JOIN subjects ON course.\"subjectId\"= subjects.id)",`

Comment: Not sure, but I think postgres can handle this as condition
```
INNER JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id AND course.deleted_at is null AND course.publish)
```

Comment: it's working.thanks

Answer (score 1):

`AND course.publish="true"` should be replaced by `AND course.publish` if it is a boolean type

`AND course.deleted_at is null AND course.publish` should be part of the `WHERE` clause rather than the `ON` clause of the joined tables because they don't participate to the join condition.

```
SELECT users.id as user_id,users.name,course.id as course_id,
       course."courseDisplayName",course.created_at,
       subjects.id as subject_id,subjects.subject
 FROM users 
INNER JOIN course 
   ON course."userId"=users.id
INNER JOIN subjects 
   ON course."subjectId"= subjects.id
WHERE course.deleted_at is null 
  AND course.publish
```

Comment: see the update question body. I've added the error i got when followed ur answer

Comment: Just look at my answer, the WHERE clause is always after the FROM clause which includes all the joined tables and associated ON clauses.